# Show that, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\beta(2n)}{n}-\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right] =...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

valid for all $s\ge 1$
$$\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^s}$$

The particular value of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=3.6256099...$

Euler's constant is defined by $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[H_n-\ln(n)\right]=\gamma$$

Euler also showed that $$\gamma=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right)$$

Where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$

Show that,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\beta(2n)}{n}-\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right] =\gamma+\ln\left(\frac{16\pi^2}{\Gamma^4\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right)$$

We are greatly appreciated if anyone can answer this  identity.

Comment: What have you attempted? Did you try to exploit the integral representation for the $\beta$ function and the fact that $$\log\frac{n+1}{n}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}-e^{-(n+1)x}}{x}\,dx $$ ?

Comment: No I haven't, but I still couldn't figure it out

Comment: Then what have you tried?

Comment: I haven't try any yet, I just took this formula out from my formula book list. I don't know how I got this formula since a few years back I can't remember, that is why I post it for someone help me to answer it so I can learn from it.

Comment: I just hope my answer won't be downvoted like the answer I gave to your other question. It is the same approach, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the same approach to [a recent question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768828/show-that-2-sum-s-1-infty-frac1-beta2s12s1-ln-left-frac-pi2),

$$ \beta(2n)-1=\frac{1}{\Gamma(2n)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1} e^{-3x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\,dx $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\beta(2n)-1}{n} = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-3x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\cdot\frac{\cosh x-1}{x}\,dx.$$
By [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html), or differentiation under the integral sign ([Feynman's trick](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf)):
$$ 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cosh x-1}{x}e^{-(3+2m)x}\,dx =-\log(m+1)+2\log\left(m+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\log(m+2),$$
hence:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\beta(2n)-1}{n} = \sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m\left(-\log(m+1)+2\log\left(m+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\log(m+2)\right)$$
is the logarithm of an infinite product that can be computed from the [limit product representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions) for the $\Gamma$ function. Namely:
$$ \sum_{m\geq 0}\left[\log\left(2m+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2m+1)-\log\left(2m+\frac{5}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\log(2m+3)\right]\\=\frac{\log 2}{2}-\log\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+\log\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right).$$
Now it is enough to use the $\Gamma$ reflection formula and the identity $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$ to express your sum in terms of $\gamma$ and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$. The original identity is, in fact, equivalent to:

> $$ \prod_{m\geq 0}\frac{(4m+3)(4m+3)(4m+6)}{(4m+2)(4m+5)(4m+5)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4}.$$