# Evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\eta(n)}{n} $ without using the Wallis Product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768828/show-that-2-sum-s-1-infty-frac1-beta2s12s1-ln-left-frac-pi2/1769206#1769206), I showed that

$$2\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\beta(2s+1)}{2s+1}=\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-2+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

where $\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}$ is the [Dirichlet Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function#Definition).

In the development, it was noted that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)&=\log\left(\frac21\cdot \frac23\cdot \frac43\cdot \frac45\cdots\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

where I used [Wallis's Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) for $\pi/2$.

---

If instead of that approach, I had used the Taylor series for the logarithm function, then the analysis would have led to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\eta(n)}{n} \tag 2$$

where $\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ is the Dirichlet eta function.

Given the series on the right-hand side of $(2)$ as a starting point, it is evident that we could simply reverse steps and arrive at $(1)$.

> **But, what are some other distinct ways that one can take to evaluate the right-hand side of $(2)$?**

For example, one might try to use the integral representation

$$\eta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+e^x}\,dx$$

and arrive at

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\eta(n)}{n} =\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x(1+e^x)}\,dx =\int_1^\infty \frac{x-1}{x^2(x+1)\log(x)}\,dx \tag 3$$

Yet, neither of these integrals is trivial to evaluate (without reversing the preceding steps).

> **And what are some other ways to handle the integrals in $(3)$?**

Comment: I am having trouble with the exact meaning of "distinct ways". Are you, for example, forbidding  the Weierstarss product formula for the sine/cosine, of which Wallis' product is a special case?  Here are 2 ways for example to evaluate the integrals:                                                                 1. expand into series of logarithms by using Frullani's integral.       2. consider a parametric form of the integral, differentiate and obtain a combination of digammas, and then integrate back.          Are these ways considered distinct?

Comment: @nospoon I invoked the first suggestion and recovered $(1)$ from the OP.  The second suggestion was posted by Olivier Oloa roughly 10 minutes before your comment posted.  ;-)) ... But, I do sincerely appreciate your comments!  Your one of the "good-people" on this site.   -Mark

Comment: I am grinning ear to ear reading these kind words, especially when they come from you, Mark. I enjoy reading your insightful answers on this site, and you are most certainly of the kind of contributors that made me stick with math.

Comment: @nospoon Noam, I enjoy, and often learn from, reading your insightful posts also.  By the way ... I wrote "your" instead of "you're" in my previous comment, thereby violating one of my own "don't say that" things.

Comment: What was the rationale for the down vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to handle $(2)$ is using the identity $$\eta\left(s\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\zeta\left(s\right)
 $$ hence, since $\eta\left(1\right)=\log\left(2\right)
 $, $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\eta\left(n\right)=\log\left(2\right)+\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\eta\left(n\right)
 $$ $$=\log\left(2\right)+\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\zeta\left(n\right)-\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\zeta\left(n\right)}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}
 $$ and now we can use the identity $$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\zeta\left(n\right)}{n}\left(-x\right)^{n}=x\gamma+\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right),\,-1<x\leq1
 $$ which can be proved taking the log of the Weierstrass product of Gamma. So $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\eta\left(n\right)=\log\left(2\right)+2\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)=\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$

Comment: @Dr.MV In our case we have to take $x=1$, which is admissible, not $x=-1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry; it's early and I was parallel processing my reading this and speaking on a conference call.   On another observation, using the Weierstass product for log(Gamma), we obtain $$\log\left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)+x\gamma = -\gamma -\log(x+1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x+1}{n}-\log\left( 1+\frac{x+1}{n}\right)  \right)$$Evidently, there is a bit more work (expanding the logarithm is a Taylor series and interchanging the order of summation) to arrive at the identity in your post.  ;-))  Solid way forward!  +1  ... -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, my explanation of the identity isn't too detailed :-D

Answer (score 4):

> *What are some other ways to handle the following integral?
>   $$
> \int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x(1+e^x)}\,dx  \tag 1
> $$*

One may set
$$
I(s):=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-sx}}{x(e^x+1)}dx, \quad s>0. \tag2
$$ We may differentiate under the integral sign, in order to get rid of the factor $x$ in the denominator, obtaining
$$
\begin{align}
I'(s)&=\int_0^\infty  \frac{e^{-sx}}{e^x+1}dx
\\\\I'(s)&=\int_0^\infty  e^{-(s+1)x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n e^{-nx} dx
\\\\I'(s)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^\infty  e^{-(n+s+1)x} dx
\\\\I'(s)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n+s}
\\\\I'(s)&=\frac12\psi\left(1+\frac{s}2\right)-\frac12\psi\left(\frac{1+s}2\right) \tag3
\end{align}
$$ where $\displaystyle \psi : = \Gamma'/\Gamma$.

Integrating $(3)$, with the fact that, as $s \to 0$, $I(s) \to 0$, we get

> $$
> \int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-sx}}{x(e^x+1)}dx=\frac12\log(\pi)+\log \Gamma\left(1+\frac{s}2\right)-\log \Gamma\left(\frac{1+s}2\right), \quad s>0. \tag4
> $$

By putting $s:=1$ in $(4)$, one obtains
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x(e^x+1)}dx=\log \left(\frac{\pi}2\right).\tag5
$$

Comment: I corrected a typographical error.  "Feynmann's Trick" was a good one here.  +1

Comment: And thank you for the post Olivier. -Mark

Comment: Olivier, I posted in an answer herein an observation that the series in Equation $(1)$ of the post can be written $$\left .\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(1+\frac{s}{n}\right) \right)\right|_{s=1}$$After differentiating prior to setting $s=1$, we obtain $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n+s}$$from which we can follow the way forward in your post.   -Mark

Comment: I've seen it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, Olivier.

Answer (score 2):

**Observation $1$:**

A suggestion made in a comment from @nospoon was to expand one of the integrals in a series and exploit Frullani's Integral.  Proceeding accordingly, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x(1+e^x)}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})}{x}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}e^{-nx}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(n+1)x}-e^{-(n+2)x}}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n} \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}$$

thereby recovering the left-hand side of Equation $(1)$ in the OP.

---

**Observation $2$:**

In the answer posted by Olivier Oloa, note the intermediate relationship

$$I'(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n+s}$$

Upon integrating $I'(s)$, as $\int_0^1 I'(s)\,ds$, we find that

$$I(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$$

thereby recovering again the left-hand side of Equation $(1)$ in the OP.