# How may we show that $\int_{0}^{1}{1-x\over 1+x}\cdot{2k+3+x^2\over 1+x^2}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over \ln x}=-\ln(2^k\pi)?$

Tags: calculus, integration

**A simple closed form**

> $$\int_{0}^{1}{1-x\over 1+x}\cdot{2k+3+x^2\over 1+x^2}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over \ln x}=-\ln(2^k\pi)\tag1$$
>   Where $k$ is a real number

**Making an attempt:**

This integral is too difficult to even try to make an attempt.

Anyway let's try $x=e^y\implies dx=e^ydy$, then $(1)$ becomes

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty}{1-e^{-y}\over 1+e^{-y}}\cdot{2k+3+e^{-2y}\over 1+e^{-2y}}\cdot{e^{-y}\over y}\mathrm dy\tag2$$

Using hyperbolic identities

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty}\tanh\left({y\over 2}\right)\cdot{2k+3+e^{-2y}\over 1+e^{-2y}}\cdot{e^{-y}\over y}\mathrm dy\tag3$$

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty}\tanh\left({y\over 2}\right)\cdot\left[(k+1)e^{2y}sech{y}+1\right]\cdot{e^{-y}\over y}\mathrm dy\tag4$$

Another try: $x=\tan y\implies dx=\sec^2y dy$, then $(1)$ becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan\left({\pi\over 4}-y\right)\cdot{2k+2+\sec^2y\over \ln\tan y}\mathrm dy\tag5$$

Still going no where!

**How can we prove $(1)?$**

Comment: hint: $ (x^a)' =\log(x)x^a$ where $'$ is a derivative w.r.t to $a$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **PRIMER:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768828/show-that-2-sum-s-1-infty-frac1-beta2s12s1-ln-left-frac-pi2/1769206#1769206), I showed using the [Wallis Product for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), the
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\log\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{2n+1}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\right)=\log(\pi/2) \tag 1$$
>
> We will use $(1)$ in that which follows.

---

We first observe that $\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}=\int_0^1 x^t\,dt$.  Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{1+x}\frac{x^2+(2k+3)}{x^2+1}\frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx&=-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^t}{1+x}\frac{x^2+(2k+3)}{x^2+1}\,dt\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^1 \int_0^1  \frac{x^t}{1+x}\left(1+\frac{2(k+1)}{x^2+1}\right)\,dx\,dt\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \log\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right) \tag2\\\\
&-(2k+2)\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^t}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}\,dx\\\\
&=-\log(\pi/2)-(2k+2)\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^t}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}\,dx\tag 3
\end{align}$$

where we used $(1)$ in going from $(2)$ to $(3)$.

Next, using the partial fraction expansion $\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{x-1}{x^2+1}\right)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^t}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}\,dx&=\underbrace{\frac12\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^t}{1+x}\,dx\,dt}_{=\frac12\log(\pi/2)\,\text{from}\,(1)}-\underbrace{\frac12 \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^t(x-1)}{1+x^2}\,dx\,dt}_{=-\frac12\log(2)+\frac12 \log(\pi/2)\,\text{from}\,(5)}\tag 4\\\\
&=\frac12\log(2)
\end{align}$$

---

In arriving at $(4)$, we used the expansion $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}$.  This results in the equality

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^t(x-1)}{1+x^2}\,dx\,dt&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \log\left(\frac{2n+3}{2n+2}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \log\left(\frac{2n+3}{2n+2}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\frac{2n+4}{2n+4}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \log\left(\frac{2n+3}{2n+4}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left((-1)^n \log\left(\frac{2n+3}{2n+4}\right)-(-1)^{n-1} \log\left(\frac{2(n-1)+3}{2(n-1)+4}\right)\right)+\log(\pi/2)\\\\
&=-\log(2)+\log(\pi/2)\tag 5
\end{align}$$

---

Putting it together, we find that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{1+x}\frac{x^2+(2k+3)}{x^2+1}\frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx=-\log(\pi/2)-(k+1)\log(2)=-\log\left(2^{k}\pi\right)$$

Comment: Well-written. I can't vote twice unfortunately.

Comment: Thamk you Zaid.  Much appreciative.

Comment: Thank you for the finest explanation @Dr.MV.

Comment: @Latte' You're quite welcome.  It was my pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: @AbuHurayrah Abu my friend.  Thank you for the 50 point bounty!!  -Mark

Comment: Show of my appreciation to you @Dr.MV

Comment: Well, I'm honored.

Answer (score 6):

By [Frullani's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem) $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}\,dx = \log\frac{b}{a}$ for any $a,b>0$. In particular
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-y}}{1+e^{-y}}\cdot\frac{e^{-y}}{y}\,dy $$
equals $\log\frac{\pi}{2}$ since it is the logarithm of [Wallis' product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product). In a similar way
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-y}}{1+e^{-y}}\cdot \frac{e^{-y}}{1+e^{-2y}}\cdot\frac{dy}{y} $$
equals $\frac{1}{2}\log(2)$ by partial fraction decomposition, and OP's $(2)$ is straightforward to compute.

Comment: The downvote. Explain. Please.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x \over 1 + x}\,{2k + 3 + x^{2} \over 1 + x^{2}}
> \,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}} =
> -\ln\pars{2^{k}\pi}:\ {\large ?}.\qquad k \in \mathbb{R}}$.

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x \over 1 + x}\,{2k + 3 + x^{2} \over 1 + x^{2}}
\,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}} =
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x}\,\pars{1 + 2\,{k + 1 \over 1 + x^{2}}}
\,{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x}\,{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x -
2\pars{k + 1}\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x}\,{1 \over 1 + x^{2}}
\,{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x \over 1 - x^{2}}\,{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x -
2\pars{k + 1}\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x \over 1 - x^{4}}
\,{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\bbx{\ds{a_{1} + 2\pars{k + 1}a_{2}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] &\
\mbox{where}\quad
a_{n} \equiv
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x \over 1 - x^{2n}}\,{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> With the identity
>   $\ds{{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}} = \int_{0}^{1}x^{t}\,\dd t}$, $\ds{a_{n}}$ becomes:

\begin{align}
a_{n} & =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t + 1} - x^{t} \over 1 - x^{2n}}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{2n}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2n}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{t/\pars{2n}\ +\ 1/n\ -\ 1}\ -\ x^{t/\pars{2n}\ +\ 1/\pars{2n}\ -\ 1} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2n}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{t + 1 \over 2n} - \Psi\pars{t + 2 \over 2n}}\,\dd t
\end{align}
Here, I used [Digamma function identity $\ds{\mathbf{6.3.22}}$ in A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm). With
$\ds{\Psi\pars{z} \equiv \totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z}}}{z}}$:
\begin{align}
a_{n} & =
\left.\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{\bracks{t + 1}/\bracks{2n}} \over
\Gamma\pars{\bracks{t + 2}/\bracks{2n}}}\right\vert_{\ t\ =\ 0}^{\ t\ =\ 1} =
\ln\pars{{\Gamma\pars{1/n} \over \Gamma\pars{3/\bracks{2n}}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{1/n} \over \Gamma\pars{1/\bracks{2n}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{\Gamma^{2}\pars{1/n} \over \Gamma\pars{3/\bracks{2n}}\Gamma\pars{1/\bracks{2n}}}
\\[5mm] 
\mbox{and} &\ 
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{a_{1}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\ln\pars{\Gamma^{2}\pars{1} \over \Gamma\pars{3/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2}} =
-\ln\pars{\pi \over 2}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{a_{2}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\ln\pars{\Gamma^{2}\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}\Gamma\pars{1/4}} =
-\ln\pars{\pi \over \pi/\sin\pars{\pi/4}} = -\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}}
\end{array}\right.\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

> With \eqref{1} and \eqref{3}:

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x \over 1 + x}\,{2k + 3 + x^{2} \over 1 + x^{2}}
\,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}} =
-\ln\pars{\pi \over 2} + 2\pars{k + 1}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}} =
\bbx{\ds{-\ln\pars{2^{k}\pi}}}
\end{align}

---

> Note that
>   $\ds{\Gamma\pars{1} = 1\,,\ \Gamma\pars{1 \over 2} = \root{\pi}}$ and the use of $\ds{\Gamma}$-*Recurrence Property* and *Euler Reflection Formula*.